# CakePHP Moved Instance to EC2, some pages not rendering from the controller, halting on error?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, amazon-ec2

**Problem Description:**
I have been developing a site in CakePHP on my local machine (pushing to github) and tried moving the page to an Amazon EC2 instance, following [this guide](http://www.rndmr.com/amazon-aws-ec2-easy-web-serverset-up-guide-with-a-mac-and-coda-2-256/) (on setting up PHP/MySQL).  The site works on my local instance (and also when I set the debug mode to '2' on the EC2 server) in core.php, but some pages display *only* the contents of the view (.ctp) files when I set the debug mode to 0.

**Attempted Solutions:**
My thought is that since the php.ini file is different on the production server, php is halting at "errors and notices," whereas on my local machine it just ignores any errors and displays the page. I looked through the entire php.ini file to see if there were any obvious settings I was missing, but couldn't find any.  I looked in my error logs, and there was an error I found (on one of the pages that only displays the contents of the view .ctp file) which I know how to fix, but I don't understand why the page would handle errors differently on my local machine (a mac) verses the EC2 instance??

**Additional Clarification**
The error I found was that I forgot to include a helper in the controller (because I use the NumberHelper when displaying the view).  When I add that helper to my array:

```
        public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Time', 'Number');
```

Then the page loads fine (obviously because I fixed the error).  But I want to know why it is halting on errors on the server side and not on my local machine?

Comment: Did you delete tmp files on the server? `some pages display only the contents of the view (.ctp) files when I set the debug mode to 0.` That's consistent with a fatal error in your layout. **Check your `app/tmp/logs/error.log`** or equivalent.

Comment: Display errors can be set within PHP as well: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
It could be set somewhere in your code.